# Imageview changes location on runtime - Swift

Tags: image, swift, tableview, cell

Hello,

My imageView that I have set in my custom table view cell moves the set image to a different place on run time.

The thing that confuses me is that if I manually set the image in the attributes inspector the image is in the place it is supposed to be. Only when setting the image programatically does this problem arise.

Below is the code I am using my cell creation function to generate the tick or cross.

```
// Cell Information

    if answersBool[indexPath.row] == false {
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "crossIcon.png")
    } else {
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "tickIcon.png")
    }
```

This is what happens on run time.

[image]

This is what the cell looks like in my storyboard.

[image]

Comment: did you added constraint to imageview in cell?

Comment: Yep! - When I go to the attributes inspector and change the image manually it doesn`t move on run time. Just when I change it using the code above it moves.

Comment: What constraints do you have on your imageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove all constraint from your imageView after that select your imageView and click on pin menu then add this five constraint shown in below Image:

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, I coped this exactly but still no luck. It goes back to the same spot in the image I posted.

Comment: Oh my bad, I just got it working - Using your constraints - Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `constraints` for your `imageView` in storyboard.

Try sticking it to right.

Comment: I have added the constraints - As I said in the question when I go to the attributes inspector and change the image manually it doesn`t move on run time. Just when I change it using the code above it moves.